# Proportional scaling in Figma's layout

Tags: html, css, figma

I'm laying out the layout [Figma's layout](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2). Interested in proportional scaling of the image in the layout

[image: main image]

Also on the layout (for completeness of the content picture)

[image: second image]

Here's what made up

```css
.techno-articles {
  margin-top: 104px;
}

.techno-articles__container {}

.techno__block_container {}

.techno-articles__items {}

.techno-article__item {}

.item__techno-article {}

.item__techno-article_example {}

.item__techno-article_content {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;*/
}

@media (max-width: 696px) {
  .item__techno-article_content {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
  .item__techno-article_body {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}


/*
.item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 0 0 calc(735 / 1441 * 100%); 
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px calc(550 / 1441 * 100%) 0px;    
}
*/

.item__techno-article_image {
  /*
  background-image: url('../img/futurearticlesimages/technoDVD.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  */
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.item__techno-article_image::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(550 / 1440 * 100%);
}


/*
.item__techno-article_image {
    background-image: url('../img/futurearticlesimages/technoDVD.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    flex: 0 0 calc(735 / 1440 * 100%);
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px calc(550 / 1440 * 100%) 0px;
}   
*/

.item__techno-article_image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__techno-article_body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: calc(96/1441*100vw);
  /*136*/
  padding-right: calc(133/1441*100vw);
  /*110*/
}

.item__techno-article_title {
  color: rgba(77, 83, 60, 1);
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 48px;
  /* or 133% */
  color: #4D533C;
}

.item__techno-article_text {
  padding-top: 24px;
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  /* or 162% */
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
}

.item__techno-article_link {
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
}

.item__techno-article_comment {
  color: #4D533C;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.145947);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 400;
  margin: -158px calc(664/1441*100vw) 0px calc(323/1441*100vw);
  /*604*/
  width: calc(453/1441*100vw);
}

.item__techno-article_comment_ownership {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author_image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_text {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 33px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author_position {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  /* identical to box height */
  color: #152934;
}

.item__techno-article_text>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.item__techno-article_link {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<section class="techno-articles">
  <div class="techno-articles__container techno__block_container">
    <div class="techno-articles__items">
      <div class="techno-article__item item__techno-article">
        <div class="item__techno-article_example">
          <div class="item__techno-article_content">
            <div class="item__techno-article_image">
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6vV.png" alt="technoDVD">
            </div>
            <div class="item__techno-article_body">
              <div class="item__techno-article_title">The wall new Balenciaga.com</div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_text">
                <p class="first__p">This article is floated online with an aim to help you find the best dvd printing solution.</p>
                <p class="second__p">Dvd printing is an important feature used by large and small DVD production houses to print information on DVDs.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_link">See Case Study</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item__techno-article_comment">
            <div class="item__techno-article_comment_text">
              “In my history of working with trade show vendors, I can honestly say that there is not one company that I've ever worked with that has better service than Exhibit Systems.”
            </div>
            <div class="item__techno-article_comment_ownership">
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_image">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZRZu.png" alt="Author comment">
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_info">
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author">Angel Armstrong</div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_position">Founder & CEO, Google</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Tell me how to achieve proportional scaling of the above image (and all content along with text) when changing screen sizes. A similar question has already been asked and I tried to apply the methods given (see [Scaling](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718042/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) and [Proportional scaling tools](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430091/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#1430094)) in these questions (**see commented css code**), but I did not succeed.

P.S. It is desirable that all content be proportionally scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the size and proportion of your HTML hero image using CSS. The approach is dependent on the width of the display screen or device.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Here, the max-width property sets the maximum width of the image to 100% of the parent element's width. The height property is set to auto, preserving the aspect ratio of the image. As the screen or device's width changes, so does the size of the image, maintaining its proportion.

You can find more examples here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp